# How to install Brother MFC-9120CN Scaner?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, scanner, brother

I need to use the scanner on my Brother MFC-9120CN printer, I'm using kubuntu 12.04. please help.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Download brscan3 and scan-key-tool here:

[brscan3 32bit 0.2.11-4](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan3-0.2.11-4.i386.deb&lang=English_gpl)

[brscan3 64bit 0.2.11-4](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan3-0.2.11-4.amd64.deb&lang=English_gpl)

[scan-key-tool 32bit 0.2.3-0](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan-skey-0.2.3-0.i386.deb&lang=English_lpr)

[scan-key-tool 64bit 0.2.3-0](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan-skey-0.2.3-0.amd64.deb&lang=English_lpr)

And follow installation instructions here:

[Scanner driver install](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1.html)

[Scan-key-tool install](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn3.html)

Comment: When you run dpkg, make sure to include the --force-all option.  I followed the instructions to the letter except I didn't bother using --force-all and I couldn't get it to work.  I installed the drivers again making sure to use it and my MFC-465CN scans properly now.